# Testcode executed but no coverage shown in actual class using Jacoco

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage, jacoco

[image]I am trying to get coverage data for a simple class.Using Junit and jacoco . I am not able to see the coverage. Looking for inputs to try and make it work .

JDK 17
Jacococo 0.8.8

Eg Class:

```
package mavenHelp;


public class Calculator {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Test code

```
package mavenHelp;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class CalculatorTest {

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        // Create a mock of Calculator
        Calculator calculatorMock = mock(Calculator.class);

        // Set up behavior for the add method
        when(calculatorMock.add(2, 3)).thenReturn(5);

        // Use the mock in your test
        int result = calculatorMock.add(2, 3);

        // Verify that the add method was called with the correct arguments
        verify(calculatorMock).add(2, 3);

        // Verify the result
        assertEquals(5, result);
    }
}
```

pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.advika</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenHelp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Add your dependencies here -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Surefire Plugin for running tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- JaCoCo Maven Plugin for code coverage -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.7</version> <!-- Use the latest version available -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I see the Testclass is covered by eclipse and the test code is covered with green as shown and the tested class is shown as red, with no lines covered. Can you help

[image]

Comment: Do u have same result, if you take `new Calculator()` instead of mock?